# Error: Cannot find module 'D:\Online Course Training\Alterra Academy Training\fe_muhammad-sholehhudin\vite\bin\vite.js'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux, vite, redux-persist

I tried to refactor my code using redux and redux-persist. But suddenly after i write all the redux code, my apps couldn't be run. It's running before i refactor it. is node.js version uncompatible with vite that i used or something else ? anybody can solve this issue ?

[image: This error message when i run this]